# Improve FFmpeg and NVENC output quality

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

Is there a way to improve the quality of the output without increasing the bitrate? Also, is there a way to improve the quality of the code using `tee`?
After reading everything I could find about `ffmpeg` and `nvenc` I was able to write these commands and they work just fine if there is no action (in-game lobby where not too many things moves), as soon as I get some action, the quality of the output drops -> artifacts all over the place. Input stream is `1080p 60fps`. GPU 1 is Nvidia Quadro p1000 with patched drivers to be able to do more than 3 concurrent connections. Input encoding is done by the GPU 0 and passed to MonaServer on localhost.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream
 -c:v h264_nvenc -cbr true -b:v 6M -preset slow -c:a copy -gpu 1 -f flv "rtmp://twitch_server/streamkey"
 -c:v h264_nvenc -cbr true -b:v 6M -preset slow -c:a copy -gpu 1 -f flv "rtmp://facebook_server/streamkey"
 -c:v h264_nvenc -cbr true -b:v 9M -preset slow -c:a copy -gpu 1 -f flv "rtmp://youtube_server/streamkey"
```

This is what I get with `ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=h264_nvenc`

```
Encoder h264_nvenc [NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder]:
        General capabilities: delay hardware
        Threading capabilities: none
        Supported hardware devices: cuda cuda d3d11va d3d11va
        Supported pixel formats: yuv420p nv12 p010le yuv444p p016le yuv444p16le bgr0 rgb0 cuda d3d11
    h264_nvenc AVOptions:
      -preset            <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding preset (from 0 to 18) (default p4)
         default         0            E..V......
         slow            1            E..V...... hq 2 passes
         medium          2            E..V...... hq 1 pass
         fast            3            E..V...... hp 1 pass
         hp              4            E..V......
         hq              5            E..V......
         bd              6            E..V......
         ll              7            E..V...... low latency
         llhq            8            E..V...... low latency hq
         llhp            9            E..V...... low latency hp
         lossless        10           E..V......
         losslesshp      11           E..V......
         p1              12           E..V...... fastest (lowest quality)
         p2              13           E..V...... faster (lower quality)
         p3              14           E..V...... fast (low quality)
         p4              15           E..V...... medium (default)
         p5              16           E..V...... slow (good quality)
         p6              17           E..V...... slower (better quality)
         p7              18           E..V...... slowest (best quality)
      -tune              <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding tuning info (from 1 to 4) (default hq)
         hq              1            E..V...... High quality
         ll              2            E..V...... Low latency
         ull             3            E..V...... Ultra low latency
         lossless        4            E..V...... Lossless
      -profile           <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding profile (from 0 to 3) (default main)
         baseline        0            E..V......
         main            1            E..V......
         high            2            E..V......
         high444p        3            E..V......
      -level             <int>        E..V...... Set the encoding level restriction (from 0 to 62) (default auto)
         auto            0            E..V......
         1               10           E..V......
         1.0             10           E..V......
         1b              9            E..V......
         1.0b            9            E..V......
         1.1             11           E..V......
         1.2             12           E..V......
         1.3             13           E..V......
         2               20           E..V......
         2.0             20           E..V......
         2.1             21           E..V......
         2.2             22           E..V......
         3               30           E..V......
         3.0             30           E..V......
         3.1             31           E..V......
         3.2             32           E..V......
         4               40           E..V......
         4.0             40           E..V......
         4.1             41           E..V......
         4.2             42           E..V......
         5               50           E..V......
         5.0             50           E..V......
         5.1             51           E..V......
         5.2             52           E..V......
         6.0             60           E..V......
         6.1             61           E..V......
         6.2             62           E..V......
      -rc                <int>        E..V...... Override the preset rate-control (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
         constqp         0            E..V...... Constant QP mode
         vbr             1            E..V...... Variable bitrate mode
         cbr             2            E..V...... Constant bitrate mode
         vbr_minqp       8388612      E..V...... Variable bitrate mode with MinQP (deprecated)
         ll_2pass_quality 8388616      E..V...... Multi-pass optimized for image quality (deprecated)
         ll_2pass_size   8388624      E..V...... Multi-pass optimized for constant frame size (deprecated)
         vbr_2pass       8388640      E..V...... Multi-pass variable bitrate mode (deprecated)
         cbr_ld_hq       8            E..V...... Constant bitrate low delay high quality mode
         cbr_hq          16           E..V...... Constant bitrate high quality mode
         vbr_hq          32           E..V...... Variable bitrate high quality mode
      -rc-lookahead      <int>        E..V...... Number of frames to look ahead for rate-control (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
      -surfaces          <int>        E..V...... Number of concurrent surfaces (from 0 to 64) (default 0)
      -cbr               <boolean>    E..V...... Use cbr encoding mode (default false)
      -2pass             <boolean>    E..V...... Use 2pass encoding mode (default auto)
      -gpu               <int>        E..V...... Selects which NVENC capable GPU to use. First GPU is 0, second is 1, and so on. (from -2 to INT_MAX) (default any)
         any             -1           E..V...... Pick the first device available
         list            -2           E..V...... List the available devices
      -delay             <int>        E..V...... Delay frame output by the given amount of frames (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default INT_MAX)
      -no-scenecut       <boolean>    E..V...... When lookahead is enabled, set this to 1 to disable adaptive I-frame insertion at scene cuts (default false)
      -forced-idr        <boolean>    E..V...... If forcing keyframes, force them as IDR frames. (default false)
      -b_adapt           <boolean>    E..V...... When lookahead is enabled, set this to 0 to disable adaptive B-frame decision (default true)
      -spatial-aq        <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Spatial AQ (default false)
      -spatial_aq        <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Spatial AQ (default false)
      -temporal-aq       <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Temporal AQ (default false)
      -temporal_aq       <boolean>    E..V...... set to 1 to enable Temporal AQ (default false)
      -zerolatency       <boolean>    E..V...... Set 1 to indicate zero latency operation (no reordering delay) (default false)
      -nonref_p          <boolean>    E..V...... Set this to 1 to enable automatic insertion of non-reference P-frames (default false)
      -strict_gop        <boolean>    E..V...... Set 1 to minimize GOP-to-GOP rate fluctuations (default false)
      -aq-strength       <int>        E..V...... When Spatial AQ is enabled, this field is used to specify AQ strength. AQ strength scale is from 1 (low) - 15 (aggressive) (from 1 to 15) (default 8)
      -cq                <float>      E..V...... Set target quality level (0 to 51, 0 means automatic) for constant quality mode in VBR rate control (from 0 to 51) (default 0)
      -aud               <boolean>    E..V...... Use access unit delimiters (default false)
      -bluray-compat     <boolean>    E..V...... Bluray compatibility workarounds (default false)
      -init_qpP          <int>        E..V...... Initial QP value for P frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
      -init_qpB          <int>        E..V...... Initial QP value for B frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
      -init_qpI          <int>        E..V...... Initial QP value for I frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
      -qp                <int>        E..V...... Constant quantization parameter rate control method (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
      -weighted_pred     <int>        E..V...... Set 1 to enable weighted prediction (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
      -coder             <int>        E..V...... Coder type (from -1 to 2) (default default)
         default         -1           E..V......
         auto            0            E..V......
         cabac           1            E..V......
         cavlc           2            E..V......
         ac              1            E..V......
         vlc             2            E..V......
      -b_ref_mode        <int>        E..V...... Use B frames as references (from 0 to 2) (default disabled)
         disabled        0            E..V...... B frames will not be used for reference
         each            1            E..V...... Each B frame will be used for reference
         middle          2            E..V...... Only (number of B frames)/2 will be used for reference
      -a53cc             <boolean>    E..V...... Use A53 Closed Captions (if available) (default true)
      -dpb_size          <int>        E..V...... Specifies the DPB size used for encoding (0 means automatic) (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
      -multipass         <int>        E..V...... Set the multipass encoding (from 0 to 2) (default disabled)
         disabled        0            E..V...... Single Pass
         qres            1            E..V...... Two Pass encoding is enabled where first Pass is quarter resolution
         fullres         2            E..V...... Two Pass encoding is enabled where first Pass is full resolution
      -ldkfs             <int>        E..V...... Low delay key frame scale; Specifies the Scene Change frame size increase allowed in case of single frame VBV and CBR (from 0 to 255) (default 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 ffmpeg.exe -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -i "Drive:\PATH\Input.webm" -c:v h264_nvenc -rc constqp -qmin 17 -qmax 51 -qp 24 -preset p7 -tune hq -pix_fmt yuv420p -rc-lookahead 4 -profile:v high -bf 0 -keyint_min 1 -refs 7 -qdiff 20 -qcomp 0.9  -me_method umh -subq 9 -me_range 36 -b:v 0 -g 300  -c:a copy  "Drive:\PATH\Output.mp4"
```

Works on GeForce GTX 1660Ti

"increasing quality without increasing bitrate", the only possible solution is getting the 'best bang for the buck', ie the best compression possible. Above are the 'standard' parameter i use for QP.

**-rc constqp :** Keeps the quality constant. In your case, there should be no artifacts if the source has none.

**-qcmin and -qcmax :** Possibly redundant as there is a fixed qp defined and used.

**-preset p7 and -tune hq :** These are possibly the most important parameters, begging brutal analysis of the video (better quality at a given bitrate).

**-rc-lookahead 4 -keyint_min 1 -qdiff 20 -qcomp 0.9 :** I dont mind KFs being close togather if the encoder feels it should place them so, this helps motion estimation vectors 'resetting' if the frames differ considerably at any point. Lookahead 4 for rate change combined with -qdiff, -qcomp set to these values gives a free hand to quickly go up and down bitrates as the frame demands.

Since '-keyint_min 1' is set, I dont mind setting KF intervel to a max of 300.

**-me_method umh :** Is redundant, included only due force of habbit.

**Bframes** are excluded, this is a personal choice and i think works better for archiving, Im prolly at odds with everyone on this, but I really prefer not having b-frames.